# Expand / Reduce symbol in TextBlock WPF/Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Simple tooltip that contains some informations,

I want to add an Expand  button (located on the top right corner of the tooltip, In a TextBlock) that allows (by click) the display of an Advanced ToolTip ,

When this advanced tooltip is displayed and When clicking on the reduce button   (located on the top right corner), the simple tooltip is displayed back.

**How can i represent these two symbols ([image] and [image]) in my textblock in order to expand/Reduce ?**

Comment: @dymanoid I'm just beginning on wpf/xaml programming, please can you be more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw custom shapes in WPF, use the `Path` element:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Path StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black" 
        Data="M 30,10 L 90,10 L 90,70 M 10,30 L 70,30 L 70,90 M 10,90 L 70,30"/>
    <Path StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black" 
        Data="M 30,10 L 90,10 L 90,70 M 10,30 L 10,90 L 70,90 M 10,90 L 70,30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The `Data` property can be used to describe a shape using a [special path markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Here is the result of this markup:

[image: screenshot]

You can customize the arrows as you wish by changing the `Data` property.